# How to apply highlight on content changed with highlight.js and contenteditable = true in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, highlight.js

I am trying to make a section of code that can be editable, keeping the highlight. For highlight support I am using highlight.js. This is the code I am trying:

```
<pre>
  <code class="sql" contenteditable="true" id="my-code">
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 1 AND s = 'qwe'
  </code>
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my-code').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e) {
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
  });
</script>
```

The section is editable and the highlight works for the initial content only. But when I modify the content, the highlight is not being applied. What should I modify in my code to make it update the highlight of the content each time when the content is changed?

Answer (score 0):

When you need a bit more control over the initialization of highlight.js, you can use the highlightBlock and configure functions. This allows you to control what to highlight and when.

Here’s an equivalent way to calling initHighlightingOnLoad using vanilla JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  });
});
```

I just copied from the [official website docs](https://highlightjs.org/usage), I hope it will help.

Comment: I have actually tried it and it didn't work for me... Can you, please, provide a full usage example that works?

Comment: jQuery('#your-btnid').on('click',function(){ document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => {
    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
  }); });

Comment: I am not sure what kind of event  you want to run it on, but what i did is i used a button click and then selected all the pre code blocks and then run a foreach on all blocks to initialize the highlight js again. now you can modify it according to your event.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I want. I need to apply the highlight each time when the content is changed. For example, if I write one character in the end of the content I want to see the correct highlight immediately. No buttons are needed in my cases.

Comment: jQuery('#your-text-area-id-or-class').on(keyup',function(){ document.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((block) => { hljs.highlightBlock(block); }); }); As i asked you to make change in the event now just put your textarea id/class in the selector and it will work like a charm when there is any change in the textarea of whatever input type you are using

Comment: I guess, you don't try your code by your own... It barely works and provides weird behavior. For example, the cursor goes to the beginning all the time, so I can't add any character to the end on the content.

Comment: *Thank you, but this is not exactly what I want. I need to apply the highlight each time when the content is changed.* Live code editing is not a supported use case for Highlight.js so it's going to be difficult to get good results. I'd recommend using another tool/library. [Disclaim: I am the current Highlight.js maintainer.]